# Solutions to $Ax=x$, where $x=(1,1,1,......1)$, for $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I know that the set of solutions $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ satisfies $\det(A-I)=0 $.
I was wondering if there was an easy to way determine what subgroup, call it $H$, this is.  How many conjugacy classes would this group (up conjugation by elements in $H$) have?  Thanks.

Comment: $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$ has $\det A = 2$ but $Ax = x$.

Comment: The condition you state is equivalent to saying that the sum of the entries in each row of the matrix is $1$. It does not entail much about the determinant.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ittay Weiss remarks in the comments, the condition $Ax = x$ does not imply that $\det A = \pm 1$.  Your condition is equivalent to the condition that $(A-1)$ has $x$ in its kernel, and also that each row in your matrix sums to $1$.

Let $e_i$ denote the standard basis vector $(0,\dots,1,0,\dots)$ with a $1$ in the $i$th spot.  Then $\{x,e_2,e_3,\dots\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb C^n$.  Let $A'$ be the matrix for $A$ in this new basis.  Then 
$$ A' = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & * & * & \dots \\
  0 & * & * & \dots \\
  \vdots & * & \ddots & \\
  0 & * & \dots & *
\end{pmatrix} $$
or, in block form, $A' = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & a \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ where $b\in \mathbb C^{n-1}$ and $a\in \mathrm{GL}(n-1,\mathbb C)$ are arbitrary.

Matrix multiplication for block matrices of this form is: 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & a  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b' \\ 0 & a'  \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & ba' + b' \\ 0 & aa'  \end{pmatrix} $$
Thus the group $H$ fixing $x$ is precisely the semidirect product $\mathrm{GL}(n-1,\mathbb C) \ltimes \mathbb C^{n-1}$.  (In the standard basis, the embedding $\mathrm{GL}(n-1,\mathbb C) \ltimes \mathbb C^{n-1} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$ for your particular $x$ requires conjugating by the change-of-basis matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 & \dots \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \ddots \end{smallmatrix}\right)$, or maybe the transpose of that.)

Conjugation by matrices of the form $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & a' \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ can put any element of $H$ into the form $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & j \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ where $j$ is a Jordan block matrix.  Conjugating then by $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & b' \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ gets you to:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b + (j-1)b' \\ 0 & j \end{pmatrix} $$
In particular, if $j-1$ is invertible, or more generally if $b$ is in the image of $j-1$, then we can take $b' = -(j-1)^{-1}b$, and thereby conjugate it away.  The clean way to say this is that up to conjugation, we care only about the class of $b$ in the cokernel of $j-1$.

Since $j$ is in Jordan form, it's easy to read off the image and cokernel of $j-1$: on each block with eigenvalue not equal to $1$, $j-1$ is invertible; for each block with eigenvalue $1$, the image is vectors starting with $0$, and so the cokernel for that block is $1$-dimensional.

Thus we see that the classification of conjugacy classes in $H$ has the following form:

- The Jordan decomposition of $\mathrm{GL}(n-1,\mathbb C)$, i.e. a partition of $n-1$ along with $\lambda \in \mathbb C^\times$ attached to each block, up to permutation.
- For each block with $\lambda = 1$, a number $b \in \mathbb C$.

There is a little bit left to do to finish the description of the conjugation classes of $H$, but I won't do it.  First, you should convince yourself that it's enough to consider conjugating first by matrices of form $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & a'\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ and then of form $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & b' \\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ as I did, so that I didn't miss some example when two claimed conjugation classes are the same.  Second, you may want to think about degenerations, i.e. how are the conjugation classes glued together.  Handling this second question really requires more advanced technology (algebraic varieties, stacks, ...), and wasn't in your original question.

Comment: Thanks! That was very insightful.  If I was interested with this group intersected with the set of matrices of determinate $\pm 1$, lets call it $\pm SL(n,\mathbb{C})$, would that just be $\pm SL(n,\mathbb{C})\rtimes \mathbb{C}^{n-1}$  ?

Comment: Hi @Nate: Well, it would not be $\pm \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb C)\rtimes \mathbb C^{n-1}$, because the action goes in the other way, i.e. $\ltimes$ instead.  (The way to remember is that it's a picture of a person with their arms sticking out crossed in front of their body, so that the person is acting on, i.e. moving around, the other one.)  But yes, $\det\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1&b\\0&a\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)=\det a$, so you have placed no condition on $b$, and you end up with $\pm\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb C)\ltimes\mathbb C^{n-1}$.

Comment: Also, I don't have a better name than $\pm SL$ for the group of matrices with determinant $\pm 1$. (Most, although not all, names for classical Lie groups refer to connected groups.)  Note that it is a central extension $(\mathbb Z/2) \ltimes SL(n,\mathbb C)$; the extension is trivial if $n$ is odd.